# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am trying to retrieve random elements from a linkedhashset. Below is my code but it is giving me exception everytime.

```
private static void generateRandomUserId(Set<String> userIdsSet) {

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String[] setArray = (String[]) userIdsSet.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println(setArray[rand.nextInt(userIdsSet.size())]);
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting-

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Ljava.lang.String;`

Can anyone help me on this? And is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: You should convert your array using `userIdsSet.toArray(new String[])` to generate a String array. Otherwise the method you are using will generate an Object array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] setArray = userIdsSet.toArray(new String[userIdsSet.size()]);
```

the [`toArray` method that takes no arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) returns an `Object[]` which can't be cast to a `String[]`. The [other version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T[]%29) returns a typed array.

Comment: @assylias Good point! In the link you provided they use new String[0]... I tested it and it works as well as your example

Comment: @Paolof76 using `new String[0]` allocates an unnecessary object so I prefer the version in my answer where possible (although the difference is minimal in most situations).

Comment: @assylias why it is different from new String[userIdsSet.size()]?

Comment: @Paolof76 if you use `set.toArray(new String[0])`, you create an empty array (`new String[0]`) and the `toArray` method will create an array of the right size. If you use `set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);`, the `toArray` method uses your array and returns it, so only one array is created.